# Deadlock issue with multithreading synchronization, how to solve?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am a beginner at Java and we were provided the following question ,
Create counter class with two methods, first method : synchronized void increment() tries to increment private variable count by 1, similarly another method synchronized void decrement decrements private variable count by 1.
If count incremented to certain value it waits for decrement to reduce count to 0 and vice versa.

```
import java.util.*;

class Mythread implements Runnable{
    Counter q;
    int i=1;
    Mythread(Counter q){
        this.q = q;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        while(i<=10){
            q.increment();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
class Mythread2 implements Runnable{
    Counter q;
    int i=1;
    Mythread2(Counter q){
        this.q = q;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        while(i<=10){
            q.decrement();
            i++;
        }   
    }
}


class Counter{
    private int count = -1;
    synchronized void increment(){
            System.out.println(++count);
            try{
                if(count>=3){
                    System.out.println("Decrement now");
                    wait();
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
            notify();
    }
    synchronized void decrement(){
            try{
                if(count<0){
                    System.out.println("Increment now");
                    wait();
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
            System.out.println(count--);
            notify();
    }
}

class q3{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Counter q = new Counter();
        Mythread t = new Mythread(q);
        Mythread2 t1 = new Mythread2(q);
    }
}
```

I tried using the notify and wait functionality to make use of synchronization and it seems to be reaching a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

works with condition above try catch to automatically end the thread

```
import java.util.*;

class Mythread implements Runnable{
    Counter q;
    int i=1;
    Mythread(Counter q){
        this.q = q;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        while(i<=10){
            q.increment();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
class Mythread2 implements Runnable{
    Counter q;
    int i=1;
    Mythread2(Counter q){
        this.q = q;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        while(i<=10){
            q.decrement();
            i++;
        }   
    }
}


class Counter{
    private int count = -1;
    synchronized void increment(){
        if(count<=3){
            System.out.println(++count);
            try{
                {
                    if (count==3){
                        System.out.println("Decrement now");
                        wait();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
            notify();
        }
    }
    synchronized void decrement(){
        if(count>0){
            System.out.println(count--);
            try{
                if(count==0){
                    System.out.println("Increment now");
                    wait();
                }
             }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
            notify();
        }
    }
}

class p2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Counter q = new Counter();
        Mythread t = new Mythread(q);
        Mythread2 t1 = new Mythread2(q);
    }
}
```